# Rails 3: Ordering by grouping in associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, associations

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859951/rails-how-to-order-a-table-by-associated-model) but that one didn't get a proper answer so I'd like to ask for myself...

I have **submissions** and **votes**.  Each submission has many votes via the usual `has_many` and `belongs_to` association.

I need to **sort the submissions by the *number of votes* they have**.  The votes table has an individual entry for each vote, with a `submission_id` associated with each record, so I can't just sort by a single column in the associated model, and that's where I'd like your help.

Answer (score 1):

Vote.all.group_by {|v| v.submission_id}.sort_by {|v| v[1].size}

---

Again, quick and dirty:

Vote.all.group_by {|v| v.submission_id}.sort_by {|v| v[1].size}.reverse

This is probably not the way you want to do it in production though. You might set up a counter cache in the submissions table(assuming 1 vote per record in the votes table):

1. Add votes_count column to submissions migration(t.integer :votes_count, :default => 0)
2. In the model(vote.rb) belongs_to :submission, :counter_cache => true

Now you can sort by votes_count in the submissions table:

Submission.order('votes_count DESC')

Comment: Using `.all` is a recipe for disaster since it loads every single record in the table and that could be a very, very large number. At the very least you should scope it. Better still, write a query that extracts only the values you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rails `counter_cache` feature.  See more [here](http://www.idolhands.com/ruby-on-rails/guides-tips-and-tutorials/using-counter-cache-with-sti-models).

Comment: Using the counter cache makes this sort of thing really fast and easy. Just be sure to index your table on the counter column to make sure the database doesn't have to sort each time.